# svg fill animation with height with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

i want this animation gradient with JavaScript which is currently work with CSS. like gradient animation through height in both svg

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
      <linearGradient id="lg" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue"/>
          <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue">
            <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s" begin="0s"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue">
            <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="10s"  begin="0s"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="url(#lg)" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>

<svg id="xcustom2" data-fill-gradient="true" fill-gradient-property="gt,0,2000">

<g id="_shape28570"  fill=url(#_GradLFF02X02X02X0002X02X02X0NA_) fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10">
<rect x="12" y="5" width="100" height="125"/>
</g>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="_GradLFF02X02X02X0002X02X02X0NA_" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0">
  <stop offset="0.000" stop-color="rgb(255,255,0)" stop-opacity="1.0"/>
  <stop offset="0.500" stop-color="rgb(0,176,80)" stop-opacity="1.0"/>
  <stop offset="1.000" stop-color="rgb(255,255,0)" stop-opacity="1.0"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use document.[createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) and it will work:

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'svg');
svg.setAttribute('viewBox','0 0 100 100');
svg.setAttribute('width',200);
svg.setAttribute('height',200);
svg.setAttribute('xmlns','http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
    
var lin = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'linearGradient');
lin.setAttribute('x1',0.5);
lin.setAttribute('y1',1);
lin.setAttribute('x2',0.5);
lin.setAttribute('y2',0);
lin.setAttribute('id','lg');

var stop1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'stop');
stop1.setAttribute('offset',0);
stop1.setAttribute('stop-color','rgb(255,255,0)');
stop1.setAttribute('stop-opacity',1);

var stop2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'stop');
stop2.setAttribute('offset',0.5);
stop2.setAttribute('stop-color','rgb(0,176,80)');
stop2.setAttribute('stop-opacity',1);
var ani1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'animate');
ani1.setAttribute('attributeName','offset');
ani1.setAttribute('values','0;1;0');
ani1.setAttribute('repeatCount','indefinite');
ani1.setAttribute('dur','10s');
ani1.setAttribute('begin','0s');

var stop3 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'stop');
stop3.setAttribute('offset',1);
stop3.setAttribute('stop-color','rgb(255,255,255)');
stop3.setAttribute('stop-opacity',1);
var ani2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'animate');
ani2.setAttribute('attributeName','offset');
ani2.setAttribute('values','0;1;0');
ani2.setAttribute('repeatCount','indefinite');
ani2.setAttribute('dur','10s');
ani2.setAttribute('begin','0s');

stop2.appendChild(ani1);    
stop3.appendChild(ani2);
lin.appendChild(stop1);
lin.appendChild(stop2);
lin.appendChild(stop3);
svg.appendChild(lin);

var circ = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
circ.setAttribute('cx',50);
circ.setAttribute('cy',50);
circ.setAttribute('r',45);
circ.setAttribute('fill','url(#lg)');
circ.setAttribute('stroke','crimson');
circ.setAttribute('stroke-width',5);
svg.appendChild(circ);

document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

Comment: @a-meshu no actully linear gradient pattern is ok just want to change 2nd svg's linear height movement. with same pattern

Comment: no ,, linear gradiewnt pattern is changed .. i want same gradient pattern as in my demo like   <linearGradient id="_GradLFF02X02X02X0002X02X02X0NA_" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0">
  <stop offset="0.000" stop-color="rgb(255,255,0)" stop-opacity="1.0"/>
  <stop offset="0.500" stop-color="rgb(0,176,80)" stop-opacity="1.0"/>
  <stop offset="1.000" stop-color="rgb(255,255,0)" stop-opacity="1.0"/>
  
</linearGradient> this pattern should be move up and down .. thanx